# Select and update date in only selected div using react-datepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am developing a react application. I have 3 div, each have DatePicker component. I want to update the date of selected. When I change the date, it gets updated every div.

Here is code -

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';

import './App.css';

import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

class Application extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { date: moment() };
    }

    dateChanged = (d) => {
        this.setState({ date: d });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange= {this.dateChanged} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.dateChanged} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.dateChanged} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Application;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how can you do it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';

import './App.css';

import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

class Application extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { date1: moment(), date2: moment(), date3: moment() };
    }

    dateChanged = (provider, d) => {
        this.setState({ [provider]: d });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.date1} onChange={this.dateChanged.bind(this, "date1")} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.date2} onChange={this.dateChanged.bind(this, "date2")} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.date3} onChange={this.dateChanged.bind(this, "date3")} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Application;
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing this, you need to provide a key and value in the state for each one

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';

import './App.css';

import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

class Application extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { date1: moment(), date2: moment(), date3: moment() };
    }

    dateChanged = (provider, d) => {
        this.setState({ [provider]: d });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.dateChanged.bind(this, "date1")} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.dateChanged.bind(this, "date2")} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <DatePicker selected={this.state.date} onChange={this.dateChanged.bind(this, "date3")} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Application;
```